# .NET MVC jQuery AJAX - JSON object as parameter not serializing values

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to figure out how to simply pass a JSON object into a controller method param. I'll often use JSON.serialize() when posting forms and the serialization to C# is automatic. However, I'm struggling to get this to work using GET while trying to load a partial.

I built a small sample project as a basic simulation of what I need, which is a controller method that accepts an int param and a separate model class, which I'd like to pass in as JSON. The partial html response is loaded into a div.

The view:

```
<div class="row">
    Loading a partial via Ajax, passing a JSON object as a param!
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div id="peoplePartial"></div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(function() {
            var id = 1;
            var person = {
                Name: "Homer Simpson",
                Age: 45
            };
            load(id, person);
        });

        function load(id, person) {
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "html",
                url: '/Home/PeoplePartial',
                data: {
                    id: id,
                    person: JSON.stringify(person)
                }
            }).done(function(data) {
                $("#peoplePartial").html(data);
            }).fail(function(data) {
                console.log(data.responseText);
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

The partial:

```
@model MVCLearning.Models.PeoplePartialModel

<div>
    <span>Person found! Name is @Model.Person.Name</span>
</div>
```

The partial ViewModel:

```
public class PeoplePartialModel {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public PersonModel Person { get; set; }
}
```

The data model/entity I'm trying to serialize:

```
public class PersonModel {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

And finally, the controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Index() {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult PeoplePartial(int id, PersonModel person) {
        if (person != null) {
            var model = new PeoplePartialModel {
                Id = id,
                Person = person
            };
            return PartialView("_People", model);
        } else {
            throw new System.Exception("An Error Has occoured");
        }
    }
}
```

The "id" param always works, of course, but the PeopleModel param is always null when using JSON.stringify(). I would have expected it to serialize to the model and contain the JSON values I passed in from the JS in the view. I can fix this by not using JSON.stringify() but then the values are always ignored e.g. always passed in as Name: null, Age: 0. I just can't seem to pass values like this.

I've tried changing the ajax call to POST but it changes nothing. I've tried setting the contentType to html and json, neither change anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For `GET` pass it without `JSON.stringify()` and in the action `PeoplePartial(int id, [FromUri]PersonModel person)`. Basically check the network tab and verify whether the data is being passed as query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. Here's the magic combination of properties:

```
    function load(id, person) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            url: "/Home/PeoplePartial",
            data: {
                id: id,
                person: person
            }
        }).done(function(data) {
            $("#peoplePartial").html(data);
        }).fail(function(data) {
            console.log(data.responseText);
        });
    }
```

I think one of the variations I had tried was POST with the contentType set. That throws an error saying both controller method params are null, strangely. I also could have omitted dataType on this and it works. I could not get *any* variation of GET to work, even though GET is what I'm trying to do. I'd really like to know why this is the case.

Comment: A GET will only work if you use `data: { id: 1, Name: "Homer Simpson", Age: 45 },` And if you omit `dataType` - the ajax function will make a best guess based on the response and work it out. And you cannot use `contentType: 'json'` for a GET because it has no body

Comment: @StephenMuecke - You're correct. Unfortunately the model I have to deal with looks as described, leaving no other option but this POST solution.

Comment: Of course you can use a GET (see the first line in my first comment)